# Mysql mistake that I cant figure out

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert data to my table:

```
 $userName="NewOrder";//use cookie to get name;
     $selectCurrentUser=" SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_name='$userName'; ";




  mysql_query(" INSERT INTO threads (topic ,date ,views ,user_id ,responses ,closed ,title ,close_voted ,content)
          VALUES('$threadTopic', NOW(), 0, '$selectCurrentUser', 0, 'false', '$threadTitle', 0, '$threadContent');") or die(mysql_error());

      mysql_close();
```

There is a mistake in my second statement. It says:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'NewOrder'; ', 0, 'false', '11111111111111111111111', 0, '
>   22222222222222222222' at line 2

My table structure:

פעולה
    thread_id   int(11)         None    AUTO_INCREMENT
    topic   varchar(50)
    date    date                None
    views   int(11)             None
    user_id int(11)             None
    responses   int(11)             None
    closed  varchar(10) utf8_unicode_ci     None
    title   varchar(100)    utf8_unicode_ci     None
    close_voted int(11)             None
    content text    utf8_unicode_ci         None

Comment: Buddy just echo the mysql query and post the result

Comment: but it is an insert..how do i echo the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things here:

1. I don't see a field in your table structure called `user_name`. Is that a typo, or might you be looking for data that isn't there?
2. Secondly, you shouldn't use a delimiter in your first statement and it should be surrounded by brackets like this:

   ```
   $selectCurrentUser="(SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_name='$userName' LIMIT 1)";
   ```
3. If that still fails then I would advise retrieving `user_id` first (using PHP) and then explicitly passing that to the second query. I would do it like this:

   ```
   $userName="NewOrder";//use cookie to get name;

   $selectCurrentUser = 0;

   // retrieve the user_id first
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_name='$userName' LIMIT 1");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
       // set $selectCurrentUser to the only id retrieved
       $selectCurrentUser = $row['user_id'];
   }

   // pass the exact user_id to the second query
   mysql_query(" INSERT INTO threads (topic ,date ,views ,user_id ,responses ,closed ,title ,close_voted ,content)
     VALUES('$threadTopic', NOW(), 0, $selectCurrentUser, 0, 'false', '$threadTitle', 0, '$threadContent')") or die(mysql_error());

   mysql_close();
   ```

   Note: I have removed the quotes from around `$selectCurrentUser` in the second query.

Comment: 1) it is from the table users..not form the table threads. It is a different table I am selecting the value from.... I get it it now..Thanks for the answer, I will be more careful next time

Comment: No problem. As a side note, have a look at `PDO`. It's a very powerful way of accessing your database (especially in larger PHP applications) and you're less likely to run into this kind of error =)

Comment: i THINK you deserver the best anser

Comment: I agree his answer was better. You should also have a look at bind variables rather than string building (just didnt have time to write a long answer as it was late in China)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `'$selectCurrentUser'`, use `($selectCurrentUser)`. Also, I don't think you should put a semicolon at the end of your first SQL statement.

**EDIT** - for clarity I mean that this statement

```
  mysql_query(" INSERT INTO threads (topic ,date ,views ,user_id ,responses ,closed ,title ,close_voted ,content)
      VALUES('$threadTopic', NOW(), 0, '$selectCurrentUser', 0, 'false', '$threadTitle', 0, '$threadContent');") or die(mysql_error());
```

should be written as follows (with single-quotes around $selectCurrentUser replaced with parentheses):

```
  mysql_query(" INSERT INTO threads (topic ,date ,views ,user_id ,responses ,closed ,title ,close_voted ,content)
      VALUES('$threadTopic', NOW(), 0, ($selectCurrentUser), 0, 'false', '$threadTitle', 0, '$threadContent');") or die(mysql_error());
```

Additionally, the following statement

```
$selectCurrentUser=" SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_name='$userName'; ";
```

should have the first semicolon removed, like so:

```
$selectCurrentUser=" SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_name='$userName' ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks from the error message that it is not taking the quotes the way you are expecting.

```
 'NewOrder'; ', 0, 'false', '11111111111111111111111', 0, ' 22222222222222222222' at line 2

  $userName="NewOrder";//use cookie to get name;
  $selectCurrentUser=" SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_name='$userName'; ";
   mysql_query(" INSERT INTO threads (topic ,date ,views ,user_id ,responses ,closed ,title ,close_voted ,content)
      VALUES('$threadTopic', NOW(), 0, '$selectCurrentUser', 0, 'false', '$threadTitle', 0, '$threadContent');") or die(mysql_error());

  mysql_close();
```

You only specify NewOrder as the first statement and put single quotes aruond it - I dont think you need to specify the semicolon at the end of the first SQL.

The error implies it is not seeing the code from the end quote of $userName to the 0 after $selectCurrentUser

You could add additional quotes and concatenate with .  like this

```
  $selectCurrentUser=" SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_name='".$userName."'";
```

and similarly for the second statement.  Hope that helps.

Comment: may be it is teh NOW() that makes the problem?

Comment: Where is exactly the mistake..seems valid to me

Comment: I found where it was. It was near the NewOrder name. I had to remove the '' around the name variable ..make it like this: WHERE user_name=$userName" .. not ==>WHERE user_name='$userName'"  --- didnt know that putting '' around a variable is wrong